# ScheduledExecutorService not printing the exception stacktrace when the run method throws NPE

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, java.util.concurrent

In code  given below, `i.intValue` is throwing `NPE`. But it is not printed. Instead the `ScheduledExecutorService` terminates silently by cancelling subsequent executions . **Why?**

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.*;
class Concurr
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService sce = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable task = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.print(".");
                Integer i = null;
                i.intValue();
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> future = sce.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        sce.schedule( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                future.cancel(true);
            }
        },10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ExecutorService` catches (and stores) all exceptions thrown in the `Runnable` and `Callable` instances it manages.

The `ScheduledFuture` has a `get()` method which throws an `ExecutionException` containing an exception if one was thrown during execution of the `Runnable`. It throws a `CancellationException` if execution was cancelled.

Do

```
System.out.println(future.get()); // returns null otherwise
```

at the end of your `main`. You will get the following output:

```
.Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Main$1.run(Main.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

You could use and pass a `Callable` instead of a `Runnable` to the `ExecutorService` if your asynchronous task should return a value. You would get that value with `future.get()`.

Each call to `future.get()` returns the result of one execution of your `Runnable`. For example, you've scheduled a task to run every 5 seconds. If after 16 seconds, you call

```
future.get();
future.get();
future.get();
future.get();
```

The code will block on the 4th call because all others have already finished and will have returned a result (unless one of them failed).